# Is a transit visa required in Jeddah for a Zimbabwean?

Tags: transit-visas, saudi-arabia, zimbabwean-citizens

I am a Zimbabwean travelling from North Cyprus to Zimbabwe. I have a layover of 15 hours in Jeddah (Saudi Arabia). Do I need a transit visa in Jeddah?

Answer (score 7):

Airlines use [Timatic](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) to display information about visas necessary for particular travelers going (or transiting in) a specific place. Putting your information into the Timatic web interface yields this:

> *26FEB19 / 1441 UTC*
>
> *National Zimbabwe (ZW)*
>
> *Transit Saudi Arabia (SA)*
>
> *Destination Zimbabwe (ZW)*
>
> *ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>   Saudi Arabia (SA)
>   TWOV (Transit Without Visa):*
>
> *Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED) or Riyadh (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours.*
>
> They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> - Only one transit stop-over in Saudi Arabia is permitted.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Passengers performing Umrah while in transit through Jeddah (JED) can obtain a transit visa up to 72 hours if:
>
> For details, click here
>
> Zimbabwe (ZW)
>
> Passport required.
>
> *- Passports issued to nationals of Zimbabwe must be valid on arrival.*
>
> *VISA NOT REQUIRED.*
>
> *Warning:*
>
> *- The official three letter country code in passports issued by Zimbabwe is ZWE. However, for a limited period, passports were issued with the three letter code of ZIM. These passports are still in circulation and will remain valid until their expiry date.*

Thus, because your onward travel will **not depart Jedda within 12 hours**, you do **need** a transit visa.