# Do Indians need transit visa to stay in Jeddah for 13 hours?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I am travelling to USA in December from India (Indian citizen) through Saudia Airlines. Unfortunately, I have a layover period of 13 hours in Jeddah. Even though I dont have any plans to leave airport do i still need to apply for a transit visa?

Comment: What is your destination airport?

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132880/is-transit-visa-required-in-jeddah):

> Airlines use [Timatic](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) to display information about visas necessary for particular travelers going (or transiting in) a specific place.

Whilst I don’t know your destination, the information on transmitting will be the same for most countries.

Putting in your information with a random destination gives this:

*TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED) or Riyadh (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.*

As your connection is 13 hours, **you will need a visa**.